#  Equivalent VB keyword for 'break'

Tags: vb.net, loops, vb6, exit

I just moved over to the Visual Basic team here at work.

What is the equivalent keyword to `break` in Visual Basic, that is, to exit a loop early but not the method?

Comment: For the other way around, in C#: *[C# loop - break vs. continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414/c-sharp-loop-break-vs-continue/6417#6417)*

Answer (score 199, accepted):

In both Visual Basic 6.0 and [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) you would use:

- `Exit For` to break from For loop
- `Wend` to break from While loop
- `Exit Do` to break from Do loop

depending on the loop type. See [Exit Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/exit-statement) for more details.

Comment: Also on a related note, "Continue" will allow you to skip to the next iteration in a for loop.

Comment: @StingyJack Worth noting that `Continue` is only available in VB.Net, not VB6

Comment: `Exit While` is not valid in VB7...use convert from `While...Wend` to `Do While...Loop` and an `Exit Do` will then work.

Comment: @Merk Exit While is documented here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/exit-statement do you have document on when it is not supported?

Comment: @StingyJack In older VB you can use `Goto <label>` and add a label at end of loop to use instead of continue. This can imo give pretty nice statements like `Goto NextDataEntry`.

Comment: @dekuShrub you can use GoTo in .net languages also, but there is usually a better alternative, like making NextDataEntry() into a function

Comment: Ah, maybe I should have mentioned @MarkJ instead of you. I just wanted to provide a way of doing it in older VB :)

Comment: Yes, I support both! `GoTo` in VB6 can be an OK way to work around the absence of the `Continue` statement. Or creating a function can work well too.

Comment: Wow, this comment conversation has been going on more than 10 years! Can't believe I only just upvoted @StingyJack's comment from 2009

Answer (score 7):

In case you're inside a Sub of Function and you want to exit it, you can use :

```
Exit Sub
```

or

```
Exit Function
```

Comment: Useful answer, but not really in the context of the question as that's what they explicitly said they didn't want to do.

Answer (score 6):

`Exit` [construct], and intelisense will tell you which one(s) are valid in a particular place.

Comment: This should have been just a comment of the above answer (John's answer).