# Is there a VB equivalent to C#'s 'continue' and 'break' statements?

Tags: vb.net, statements

For sake of argument, how could I do this in VB?

```
foreach foo in bar
{
   if (foo == null)
       break;

   if (foo = "sample")
       continue;

   // More code
   //...
}
```

Comment: Exit For, Exit Select etc., and you can always fake a break; statement with a GoTo statement and a Line Label. Many people frown on GoTo statements btw. and I found that whenever I do use them they always disappear in the rewrite.

Comment: For the other way around, in C#: *[C# loop - break vs. continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414/c-sharp-loop-break-vs-continue/6417#6417)*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

-- Edit:

You've changed your question since I've answered, but I'll leave my answer here; I suspect a VB.NET programmer will show you how to implement such a loop. I don't want to hurt my poor C# compilers feelings by trying...

-- Old response:

I believe there is

```
Continue While
Continue For
```

and

```
Exit While
Exit For
```

Comment: Your response seems to work. Exit For seems to apply to the VB's For Each.  Once I verify, I'll mark your answer.

Comment: @Blinky - old now, but Exit For definitely still works in vb.net

Answer (score 5):

I thought a VB.NET example may help in the future:

```
Sub breakTest()
    For i = 0 To 10
        If (i = 5) Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(i)
    Next
    For i = 0 To 10
        If (i = 5) Then
            Continue For
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

The output for break:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

And for continue:

```
0
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
```