# C# go to next item in list based on if statement in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I am using C#.  I have a list of items.  I loop through each item using a `foreach`.  Inside my `foreach` I have a lot of `if` statements checking some stuff.  If any of these `if` statements returns a false then I want it to skip that item and go to the next item in the list.  All `if` statements that follow should be ignored.  I tried using a break but a break exits the whole `foreach` statement.

This is what I currently have:

```
foreach (Item item in myItemsList)
{
   if (item.Name == string.Empty)
   {
      // Display error message and move to next item in list.  Skip/ignore all validation
      // that follows beneath
   }

   if (item.Weight > 100)
   {
      // Display error message and move to next item in list.  Skip/ignore all validation
      // that follows beneath
   }
}
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Use `continue;` instead of `break;` to enter the next iteration of the loop without executing any more of the contained code.

```
foreach (Item item in myItemsList)
{
   if (item.Name == string.Empty)
   {
      // Display error message and move to next item in list.  Skip/ignore all validation
      // that follows beneath
      continue;
   }

   if (item.Weight > 100)
   {
      // Display error message and move to next item in list.  Skip/ignore all validation
      // that follows beneath
      continue;
   }
}
```

Official docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but they don't add very much color.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that continue was to carry on in the body of the foreach.

Comment: @Brendan - to do that, you just don't use any control statements, as if it were a cascade of `if` statements outside a loop.

Comment: For anyone else viewing this thread that is using VB, the syntax is [code] Continue For [/code]

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
foreach (Item item in myItemsList)
{
  if (SkipCondition) continue;
  // More stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 23):

You should use:

```
continue;
```

Answer (score 9):

The `continue` keyword will do what you are after.  `break` will exit out of the `foreach` loop, so you'll want to avoid that.

Answer (score 7):

Use `continue` instead of `break`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

continue; will work how you are expecting break; to work here.

continue; will skip to the next item in the foreach loop

break; will break out of the loop and continue the code where thr foreach loop ends.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).