# C# foreach loop item soft "break"

Tags: c#, foreach, skip

let's say I have a foreach loop to perform some processing on List MyTypeInstanveVariable

```
foreach(MyType item in MyTypeInstanceVariable) {
    if (cond1) {}

    if (cond2) {}
}
```

If cond1 is  met I want to advance to the next item in the MyTypeInstanceVariable. Now I could add a little boolean to check whether to evaluate cond2, but is there some built in command that will quickly move onto the next item? I can't use break as that would break out of the foreach loop altogether

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# go to next item in list based on if statement in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266456/c-sharp-go-to-next-item-in-list-based-on-if-statement-in-foreach)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the `continue` statement.

Comment: we've all been there before ;-)

Answer (score 2):

perhaps continue?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(v=vs.71).aspx