# How to check if the file exist in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to check if the file inside my device exist. When the variable **crphoto1** is empty or the file does not exist the "**Photo1**" json should be `{"Photo1", ""}`

```
JObject ph1json = string.IsNullOrEmpty(crphoto1)
? new JObject
{
    {"ContactID", crcontactID},
    {"Photo1", ""}
}
: new JObject
{
    {"ContactID", crcontactID},
    {"Photo1", File.ReadAllBytes(crphoto1)}
};
```

Comment: So you just want to check if a file exists in device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for how to check if file exist you can use

```
    using System.IO;

    string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment
     .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "yourfile.jpg");

    JObject ph1json;
    bool doesExist = File.Exists(fileName);
    if (!doesExist || string.IsNullOrEmpty(crphoto1))
    {

      ph1json = new JObject 
      {
         {"ContactID",crcontactID},
         { "Photo1",""}
      };
    } 
    else
    {
      ph1json = new JObject
     {
      {"ContactID",crcontactID},
      {"Photo1",File.ReadAllBytes(crphoto1)}
     };
    }
```

Comment: How about in looping I want to skip if the file does not exist do I just add return?

Comment: you can use return to skipe the loop if you are using it

Comment: you can also use  continue; or break; depending what you are really doing

Comment: You can read about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414/c-sharp-loop-break-vs-continue

Comment: crphoto1 contains the path file of the image is it ok if I use this "bool doesExist = File.Exists(crphoto1 );"?