# Xamarin Forms: Get the path of an image file stored on the shared project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, shared-project

I am trying to upload an image file as `ByteArrayContent` through my web service. I have added all the images to the shared project and set the build action as `Embedded resource`.

Following is my code:

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("Avatars." + selectedAvatar);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
content.Add(byteContent, "file", selectedAvatar);
```

When I try like above I am getting `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Projectname.Avatars.ic_avatar01_xx.png"`

Added the images directly inside a folder in the shared project like the below screenshot.

[image]:

I tried changing the . with a / in the file path, like below:

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("Avatars/" + selectedAvatar);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
content.Add(byteContent, "file", selectedAvatar);
```

But in that case, I am getting the `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Avatars/ic_avatar01_xx.png"`

**What is the correct way to get the path of an image file stored on a shared project?**

Also tried another approach:

```
string avatarFileName = "Avatars/" + selectedAvatar;
var assembly = typeof(ProfilePage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{avatarFileName}");
content.Add(stream, "file", avatarFileName);
```

But in the above case I am getting the below error:

[image]

Comment: We can only get the stream of the image if we put the image file in project directly . If you do want to implement it you need to put the image to local or sd card . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54663101/how-to-check-if-the-file-exist-in-xamarin-forms .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Is it possible to convert the stream into `System.Net.Http.HttpContent`? I need to pass the data in that format through service.

Comment: Do you want to upload the image stream with httpclient ?

Comment: Got solution from here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/186014/xamarin-forms-get-the-path-of-an-image-file-stored-on-the-shared-project/p1?new=1

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Yes I am trying to upload image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload the image with Stream , you could check the following code

```
private async Task<string> UploadImage(Stream FileStream)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://your.url.com/");
            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            HttpContent content = new StringContent("fileToUpload");
            form.Add(content, "fileToUpload");
            content = new StreamContent(FileStream);
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = "fileToUpload",
                FileName = "xxx.png"
            };
            form.Add(content);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://your.url.com/", form);
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
```

#### Option 2:

You could also use the plugin **[FileUploaderPlugin](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FileUploaderPlugin)** . It support uploading multiple files at once

Uploading from a file path

```
CrossFileUploader.Current.UploadFileAsync("<URL HERE>", new FilePathItem("<REQUEST FIELD NAME HERE>","<FILE PATH HERE>"), new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
               {"<HEADER KEY HERE>" , "<HEADER VALUE HERE>"}
            }
);
```

#### Option 3:

The first parameter of MultipartFormDataContent is HttpContent. To handle the stream, try using the [StreamContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.streamcontent?view=netcore-3.1) type which inherits from the HttpContent. Get the streamContent from the stream and add id to the MultipartFormDataContent.

```
string avatarFileName = "Avatars." + selectedAvatar;
var assembly = typeof(ProfilePage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{avatarFileName}");
var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
content.Add(streamContent, "file", avatarFileName);
```